# Dificuldade com PDO

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

Estou iniciando com o uso de **PDO** e estou com uma dúvida que não consegui resolver. Faço o *select* abaixo que irá me retornar 2 horários:

```php
$sqlSaida = 'SELECT horario 
               FROM HORARIOS
              WHERE COD = :codsaida 
              UNION
             SELECT horario 
               FROM HORARIOS
              WHERE COD = :codretorno;';

$resSaida = $conexao->prepare($sqlSaida);

$resSaida->execute(array(
    ':codsaida' => $codsaida,
    ':codretorno' => $codretorno
));

$saidas = $resSaida->fetchAll();
```

Mas não consigo armazenar os resultados, abaixo consigo exibir ambos, mas como poderia armazenar eles em variaveis diferentes?

```php
foreach ($saidas as $saida) {
 echo $saida['horario'];
}
```

Comment: Qual a finalidade dessas variáveis?

Comment: preciso passar elas em outro select a frente.

Comment: Que select da frente? não deu para enteder qual é o seu objetivo com esse código.

Comment: eu faço esse select e vou usar o resultado em outro select e depois em um insert.

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adcione essas informações e código também. Essa consulta retorna uma linha ou mais?

Comment: A resposta abaixo solucionou minha duvida. Obrigado.

Comment: O array montado na resposta tem a mesma estrutura de `$saidas`. Se resolveu ta valendo :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cria um `array`.

```php
    $arrData = []; 
    $x = 0;
    foreach ($saidas as $saida) {
       $arrData[$x]['horario'] = $saida['horario'];
       $arrData[$x]['retorno'] = $saida['retorno'];
       $x++;
    }

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r($arrData['horario']);
    echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: Esse código ai vai retornar um array com o último elemento de `$saidas`.

Comment: É verdade. Respondi na pressa. Thanks.

Comment: Exatamente isso! Muito obrigado!